# Compare numpy arrays whose entries are strings, and find locations of strings

Tags: python, numpy

I have **two numpy arrays whose entries are strings**. The first array (`array1`) is of shape `( m, n )` where m>1 and n>1. The second array (`array2`) is of shape `(p, )`, where p is an integer greater than 1. **Entries in array2 are not repeated (i.e. they are unique)**, while array1 is likely to have multiple instances of same strings.

I want to **replace array1 with another array** of the same shape (as array1), **by including indices (numbers) in place of strings**. These indices are obtained by **comparing the entries of array1 with array2**. Each entry of array1 will surely match with some entry of array2.

**Speed is of importance here**, and I want to find the fastest way of doing this.

Here is a small example:

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.asarray([['aa', 'cc', 'bb', 'aa', 'aa', 'bb'],
                   ['cc', 'bb', 'cc', 'bb', 'aa', 'aa'],
                   ['bb', 'cc', 'aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc']])

array2 = np.asarray(['aa', 'bb', 'cc'])
```

This is how I am approaching the problem for now:

```
for k in range(array1.shape[0]):
    array1[k] = np.asarray([j for i in range(array1.shape[1]) for j in range(len(array2)) if array1[k,i]==array2[j]]) 

print array1

[['0' '2' '1' '0' '0' '1']
 ['2' '1' '2' '1' '0' '0']
 ['1' '2' '0' '0' '1' '2']]
```

But, when I work with array1 with huge numbers of rows and columns, I find that the above mentioned way is not very fast.

What may be a faster way of achieving the task that I desire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With all entries from `array2` present in `array`, we can use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
sidx = array2.argsort()
out = sidx[np.searchsorted(array2,array1.ravel(),sorter=sidx).reshape(array1.shape)]
```

If `array2` is already sorted, we can skip `argsort` and corresponding indexing step -

```
out = np.searchsorted(array2,array1.ravel()).reshape(array1.shape)
```

Comment: Divakar: Fantastic answer, like always. Many thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

A possible alternative:

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.asarray([['aa', 'cc', 'bb', 'aa', 'aa', 'bb'],
                     ['cc', 'bb', 'cc', 'bb', 'aa', 'aa'],
                     ['bb', 'cc', 'aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc']])

array2 = np.asarray(['aa', 'bb', 'cc'])

d = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(array2)}
result = np.vectorize(d.get)(array1)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[0 2 1 0 0 1]
 [2 1 2 1 0 0]
 [1 2 0 0 1 2]]
```

Comment: Daniel: Thanks very much for your answer. It is fast and it works like a charm. =)

Comment: @SiddharthSatpathy Glad I could help!